# Converting a String to List in Python

Tags: python, django, string

I'm trying to create a list from arguments I receive in a url.

e.g I have:

```
 user.com/?users=0,1,2
```

Now when I receive it in the request it comes as a string. I want to make a list out of "0,1,2" [0,1,2]

Comment: removed the django tag as it's not really a django question

Comment: But Django may have some support for parsing URLs that may be of interest.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `split` method.  Example:

```
>>> "0,1,2".split(",")
['0', '1', '2']
```

Or even,

```
>>> [int(x) for x in "0,1,2".split(",")]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 7):

This question was originally tagged Django, so I'll proceed with that in mind.

Inside your view function, the `request` object has a GET attribute that is an instance of a [QueryDict](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects). If you always know that you are going to get a comma separated list of integers for the key "users", you could do something like this in your view function:

```
users_list = request.GET('users', "").split(',')
```

That will give you a list of strings, or an empty list if "users" wasn't supplied in GET. If you wanted a list of integers you could process it further with a list comprehension:

```
users_list = [int(x) for x in users_list]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import ast
x=ast.literal_eval('0,1,2')
print(x)
# (0, 1, 2)
```

`ast.literal_eval` is like `eval`, but completely safe since it restricts the string to literals such as strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans and `None`.

Another alternative, not yet mentioned, is to use `map`:

```
x=map(int,'0,1,2'.split(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

To go from "0,1,2" to ['0','1','2'] its just `"0,1,2".split(",")`

So if you have it in a variable `users`, then `users.split(",")` will give you the list.

If you need them as ints instead of strings, it would be `[int(x) for x in users.split(',')]`.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the string to a list, use `split`.

To convert the list of strings to a list of integers, use a list comprehension with `int`.

So putting it all together, it looks something like this:

```
s = '0,1,2'
l = [int(x) for x in s.split(',')]
```

Results:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, as I haven't used the framework, but I'd imagine Django wouldn't make him parse the entire query string himself, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
s = 'user.com/?users=0,1,2'
s.rpartition('?users=')[2].split(',')
```

Answer (score -2):

You have eval to convert string to "real code":

Example:

```
>>> l = u"[('0','None'),('2','Taxable Goods'),('4','Shipping')]"
>>> type(l)
<type 'unicode'>

>>> t = eval(l)
>>> type(t)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: He definitely asked for something else!